# Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie input troubles

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

I'm using Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie in Unity to Play a movie in iOS and Android devices.

Actually it works pretty well in Android but in iOS, specifically on iPhone 5, the first time the video is played the device stops looking for inputs.

It means that the UI controls over the video doesn't work the first time the user played it. I can´t pause it, turn up or down volumes or even stop the video. If I want to stop the video I need to quit the app.

This happen just the first time I reproduce a video. After that I'm able to play again that video, or even a new one, the UI works again and I'm able to use the Volume buttons or quit the video using the UI buttons.

My first thought was on the iOS version in the device but it has the latest one, iOS 8.3; In others iOS devices I don't have any trouble even when they doesn't have the latest iOS version. It seems to be just a iPhone 5 Trouble.

If any one have a clue about what is happen I'll be glad to hear you.

Here is my code :

```
#if UNITY_IOS 
    Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie (videoURL,
                                  Color.black,
                                  FullScreenMovieControlMode.Full,


    FullScreenMovieScalingMode.AspectFit);
#endif


#if UNITY_ANDROID
    Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie (videoURL,
                                  Color.black,
                                  FullScreenMovieControlMode.Minimal/*,


    FullScreenMovieScalingMode.AspectFit*/);
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I just figureout what is just happen.

It semms like I was calling Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie right before I swap the screen orientation to be LandscapeLeft and inside the same function. For some reason this swap movement derives in the imposibility of catch the touch in Iphone5 at the fisrt time I play the video.

The strange thing is that if I switch the ScreenOrientation to Landscape with one button and after that I call Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie with another button, everything works great.

My solution was to put Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie inside a corrutine and at the end of my function to swap Screen orientation to Landscape call my function to play the video.

Prety much like this:

```
IEnumerator StartUnityVideo()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
    Debug.Log ("StartUnityVideo");

        Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie (videoURL,
               InterfaceColor,
               FullScreenMovieControlMode.Full,
               FullScreenMovieScalingMode.AspectFit);
        Debug.Log ("FIN Iniciando video");
}
```

and my function to swap orientation

```
public void SwapOrientation()
{
    Screen.orientation = ScreenOrientation.LandscapeLeft;
    StartCoroutine ("StartUnityVideo");
}
```

And that's all. It needs to use some minors UI screens to ensure it doesn't look strange because of the Screen orientation Swap but it works.